# Stopping return of ArcGIS to tool dialog when tool fails?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, geoprocessing-framework

When a tool processed in foreground fails, I have some time to read the log. After closing the log I get redirected to the tool dialog, where I stopped just before executing the tool. I know this is often handy, but while debugging models, I'd prefer it if the next step after closing the log was plain document (like when running the tool in background) or even "model builder" window.

Is there any way to change this behavior (except for running all the processes in background, which is not what I want for other reasons, or running the model from ModelBuilder, which is not possible with "white boxes")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @KHibma:

> I can confirm, theres no option to modify this behavior. Thats how it
>   works. In the new ArcGIS Pro app, the dialogues will behave a bit
>   differently than this.